# Open differents links with the same function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I have a little problem with my JS. I have several links with same **onclick**.
My problem is when click on a link, the first **onclick** display.

**My HTML**

```
<li>
    <a href="#" onclick="openRookie();" class="rookie">John Doe</a>
    <p class="open">
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="#">Twitter</a>
        <a href="#">Dribbble</a>
    </p>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" onclick="openRookie();" class="rookie">John Doe</a>
    <p class="open">
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="#">Twitter</a>
        <a href="#">Dribbble</a>
    </p>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" onclick="openRookie();" class="rookie">John Doe</a>
    <p class="open">
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="#">Twitter</a>
        <a href="#">Dribbble</a>
    </p>
</li>
```

**My JS**

```
var s = document.getElementsByClassName('open');
function openRookie() {
    for(var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i].style.maxHeight !== "20px") {
            s[i].style.maxHeight = "20px";
            s[i].style.marginTop = "10px";
        } else {
            s[i].style.maxHeight = "0";
            s[i].style.marginTop = "0";
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse the same function by targeting the element which triggered the event. Then using this element, you can get the different html nodes involved in the event.

For example see this http://jsfiddle.net/65Xxw/1/

```
function openRookie(){

    // get the anchor which has been clicked.
    var elm = event.target;
    // get the parent node which is the li tag
    var parent = elm.parentNode;
    // get the child of the li tag which is a paragraph. 
    var paragraphs = parent.getElementsByTagName('p');

    // paragraphs is an array. we know there is only one so can just show.
    paragraphs[0].style.display = "block";

    // prevent the link from doing it's natural thing.
    return false;

}
```

You could also change this to specifically look for the open class if you ended up with multiple `<p>` tags within the `<li>`

Comment: I had not thought to use target and parentNode. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give the `<p>` that you want to show/hide an id that you can reach and then use `getElementById` instead. The ID should be passed into the function as a parameter.